# How to fix Microsoft Edge displaying incorrect table cell widths when child element with defined width is within a cell with a colspan?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, microsoft-edge

Pretty hard to explain, but easier to show via [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdb47t1L/1/)

I have a `table` with 3 cells:

```
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td style="background:blue;width:60%;">Some text for 1st cell</td>
      <td style="width:40%;background:red;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="width:100%;background:yellow;"><div style="width:400px;">
      test
      </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The `table` has a `width` of 100%:

```
.table {
  width:100%;
}
```

When a child element with a defined `width` is placed within the bottom cell which has a `colspan`, Microsoft Edge displays the incorrect `width`s for the top cells.

They should be showing like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, Microsoft edge is showing it like this:

[image]

Removing the child element (or its `width`) and everything is fine again.

How do I fix this problem? I need to keep the `table` widths as percentages and the child element as a fixed `width`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just add [`table-layout:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

> fixed
>
> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.
>
> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once
>   the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed
>   up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent
>   cell content may not fit in the column widths provided. Any cell that
>   has content that overflows uses the overflow property to determine
>   whether to clip the overflow content.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 500px
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed
}
.cell1 {
  background: blue;
  width: 60%
}
.cell2 {
  background: red;
  width: 40%
}
.cell3 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%
}
.cell3 div {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="cell1">Some text for 1st cell</td>
      <td class="cell2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="cell3">
        <div>
          test
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: table-layout:fixed was exactly what I needed!