# How to resolve the table layout fixed issue in edge browser?

Tags: css

Here i am getting the issue with edge browser. with table-layout:fixed its working fine in firefox and chrome browser.

My situation is like i have table below:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal vlc-slds-table" ng-init=digestOnResize() ng-if="set.length">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title_caps slds-text-heading--label">
            <th width="20px" ng-style="{'padding':'0px'}"></th>
             <th scope="col" ng-repeat='ctrl in set' ng-hide='!ctrl.displayInView'>
                <div class="slds-truncate">{{::ctrl.eleArray[0].propSetMap.label}}</div>
            </th>
            <th width="70px"/>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='vlc-slds-block_table-body'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="vlc-asterix icon-v-asterix vlc-editblock-asterix" ng-if="isEditBlockRecordInvalid($index, this)"></span>
            </td>
            <td class='vlc-slds-block_table-body__td' data-label='{{::child.eleArray[0].propSetMap.label}}' ng-repeat='child in children = control.children' ng-hide='!child.displayInView'>
                <form name="editblockform" 
                      class="vlc-slds-edit-block__form" 
                      ng-if='child.eleArray[0].propSetMap.hide||(!child.eleArray[0].propSetMap.show || evaluateShow(child.eleArray[0], this))'
                      ng-include="'vlcEditBlockDetailCont.html'">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td data-label='{{::customLabels.OmniEditBlockTableMenu}}'>
                <div class="vlc-slds-edit-block--button-menu">
                    <slds-dropdown content="[]" template-url="vlcEditBlockDropdown.html"></slds-dropdown>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

And i am using the css for this like below:

```
.slds-table slds-table--bordered {
   table-layout: fixed; 
 }
table td, .via-slds .slds-table th {
    padding: .25rem .5rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

It working fine in chrome browser like below screen shot:
[image]

But its not applied on the edge browser its displaying like below:

[image]

Can somebody help me to guide how can i resolve it?

Comment: [How to fix Microsoft Edge displaying incorrect table cell widths when child element with defined width is within a cell with a colspan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867901/how-to-fix-microsoft-edge-displaying-incorrect-table-cell-widths-when-child-elem)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are looking for, I came across the same issue just now. After playing around with `CSS` and searching for answers. I believe this is a edge case with Edge that causes tables to render incorrectly with `table-layout:fixed;` and `width:100;`

I am still not sure how this fixes it for me but explicitly setting the width on the table to auto seems to resolve the issue.